# How do I use javascript to get the result from radio button and display it at the last page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 html pages: 1st 1 has a radio button question, the second page will have a second question, the 3rd page will simply show/display the result of selection. (ie. The user selects a) Apple )

The html part is easy, but I don't know how to write the javascript part.

Please help.

Comment: It's possible with JavaScript (using cookies or Local Storage), but the traditional way to do that is to use a server-side technology, and sessions. Or keep it all in a single page, and toggle content chunks as appropriate.

Comment: _"..but I don't know how to write the JavaScript part."_. Then start by going to Google first, search for [JS tutorials](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics), start building your script and when you have a specific problem come back with the code and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
<script>
    function showQuestion()
    {
        document.getElementById("question2").style.display = 'inline';
    }
    function showResults()
    {
        document.getElementById("results").style.display = 'inline';
    }
</script>

<div id="question1">
    <select onchange="showQuestion()">
      <option value="0">Choose something</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="question2" style="display: none;">
    <select onchange="showResults()">
      <option value="0">Choose something</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="results" style="display: none;">

</div>
```

Note that I did not use multiple pages, as then you'd need a way to save the user data, i.e. what he chose, and load it on another page. Thus you'd require a server side technology or some client side tricks to remember the choice.

Also, jQuery is a fantastic way of writing javascript that's faster to write and easier to get things done. My code above is pure javascript.

Comment: Just to add to this, one could use a cookie as a possible way to store the data and display it on another page. It's also possible to cause the link to the next page to automatically include the data in the URL and then have javascript parse the URL like a server side language usually would. Both of those aren't really good solutions and learning php might be very beneficial.

Comment: agreed with above. I opted for the simplest solution.